# Yii min length validator allowing blank inputs

Tags: yii

I have the following code within a model

```
rules()
{
....
array('new_pass', 'length', 'min'=>6, 'max'=>64, 'tooShort'=>'Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)'),        
....    
}
```

When I input a value that is between 1 and 5 chars long it errors saying it is too short. But if I leave it blank it updates? I'm not sure how to fix this or more importantly why it would let a blank value in.

I tried adding in a allowEmpty, that stopped it updating a password that was 0 length in chars but when I tried to then save the model with a 6+ length password it then error'd saying Password too short'

Any help greatly appreciated

Jonny

Comment: U don't want to make password compulsory ??

Comment: This is for updating a password. So by putting it as required, won't it be required on a registration also? Because it wouldn't exist at that point.

Comment: So at the time of registration u allow password field to be blank ??
Sorry i am confused explain it with little clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i understand its changepassword action so just add rule:

```
rules()
{...
array('new_pass','required','on'=>'youraction')
...}
```

But still `'allowEmpty'=>false'` must work for this.

Comment: I thought about this after I left my computer. I believe this to be the solution. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add `tooLong`, then try it again

Comment: I don't think I really need a 'tooLong' message, 64 is the max length. Anyway I tried it and it still accepts blank passwords.

Comment: @Jonnny add `'allowEmpty'=>false'`,default value is `true`

Comment: I added 'allowEmpty'=>false before, it doesn't let save the model. It returns 'Password too short...' even though the password is long enough.

Comment: before save model,use `echo yourmodel->new_pass;` to make sure the value is you input,if it is,then i've no idea about it,anyway this rule works fine on my computer